# Use MySQL to generate semi random string on insert

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to know if its possible to have mysql generate a semi random string when a new entry is inserted into a table.

so if my table has a column called Code , when a new record is inserted can mysql generate a random string of numbers and add that onto the end of what was inserted into code.

eg if MCQ is inserted into code , mysql will do its thing and add 123 onto it giving  MCQ123

Comment: Yes. Have you explored the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand)?

Comment: sure, a trigger could do this if you want this to be an automated process along with what @JayBlanchard said.

Comment: *Straight shootin' Ralph!* @Fred-ii-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible using `TRIGGER`. But why not inserting the random string with the insert data?